# How to fix "NoSuchMethodError" error in log4j

Tags: java, elasticsearch, log4j

I'm developing a java application which uses elasticsearch. I use elasticsearch api in java. I'm getting NoSuchMethodError error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger.trace(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V

I have included my pom file

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: What is the solution for this @lavan-giri

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Log4j dependency that you have on the classpath. For elasticsearch 5.4.x you need Log4j 2.8.2 (api and core), not 2.3. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/5.4/_log4j_2_logger.html